# Decompile qt exe

Tags: c++, qt, decompiler

I have an EXE file made by qt framework, I think it's written in C++ language but I'm not sure.
I want to **decompile** the file, I tried more than 5 software but there is no one can display C++ code as well, so I need any software to help me to read EXE code because I need it to re-write in another language.
I need the EXE logic at least
some of softwares that I use it:

```
snowman
PEiD
idafree50
idademo695_windows
C-Decompiler
```

Thanks

Comment: Everything nice and readable is stripped away and the results look like they have been run through a blender by the time an optimizing compiler is done with C++ source code. You will be able to get the generated machine instructions and some of that will be recognizable as common patterns to accomplish common tasks by people familiar with a given compiler, but you can't expect much more than that.

Comment: exe doesn't know anything about C++, it only contains machine language `0s` and `1s` so how can your program to know that this `0` or `1` was produced by C++ or java? they only build it back generating algorithms then they add C++ code. keep in mind no program will be 100% accurate in such scenario of reverse engineering

Comment: In addition to being impossible, it's probably also [illegal or at least unethical](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30359/is-decompiling-software-considered-unethical-or-illegal)

Answer (score 9):

What you are asking is (very close to) impossible.

When the original C++ code was interpreted, native machine code was generated. There is no way to go back from that to the original C++.
That's like asking someone to go from 9 back to the original "3+3+3". But who knows if that was the original? Noone can tell from "9" - it may have been "8+1"..

Sure, you can still read the generated asm and try to work out what the code does, but that is *hard* and you still won't get the original C++ back.